# Optimising Bulk Select statements for SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have a database table:

```
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
, X INTEGER
, Y INTEGER
, Value INTEGER
```

There are 1,050,625 records, and I call them using

```
SELECT Value
FROM Tablename
```

I just want all the records from the fourth column. My function stores these into an array, but getting all this data takes nearly five minutes.

Is there a faster way to get this data?

Answer (score 0):

increase the sqlite cache via `PRAGMA cache_size=<number of pages>`. the memory used is `<number of pages>` times `<size of page>`. (which can be set via `PRAGMA page_size=<size of page>`)

by setting those values to 16000 and 32768 respectively (or about 512MB), i was able to get this one program's bulk load down from 20mins to 2mins. (although i think that if the disk on that system wasn't so slow, this might not have had as much effect)

but you might not have this extra memory available on lesser embedded platforms, i don't recommend increasing it as much as i did on those, but for desktop or laptop level systems it can greatly help.